# Слово "халупа"

Tags: этимология

Халупой называют ветхое, убогое строение. А что это вообще за слово, каково его происхождение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Родственные слова есть в украинском, польском, чешском, словацком.

Есть еще версия, что **халупа** - производное от слав. *хаl- с суф. -uр-а; ср. польск. сhаłра из* хаl-р-а. Слав. *хаl- "кустарник у воды" сближается с лат. saliх "ива", ирл. sail, д.-в.-н. sаlаhа.

По Фасмеру, слово **халупа**, возможно, родственно *халуга*, то есть первонач. "плетеный шалаш", "ограда", церк., русск.-цслав. *халуга* "тын, изгородь", также "улица"; халужина "длинная хворостина"; терск., укр. халуга "водоросль", блр. халуга "шалаш, сплетенный из прутьев", ст.-слав. халѪга. Достоверной этимологии слово не имеет.